# HTML/CSS aligning ul items

Tags: html, css

How can I put these items in the middle?

Like this:

[image]

Here is my HTML and CSS code:

```css
nav {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 5px 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-bar">
</div>
<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="views.png">
  </div>
  <div class="toggle">
    <a href="#">
      <ion-icon name="menu-outline"></ion-icon>
    </a>
  </div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Подписка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Кино</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Сериалы</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <ion-icon name="log-out-outline"></ion-icon>Войти</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

`Align-items : center;` doesn't work and justify content as well

Comment: `align-items:center;` controls the alignment of **children** of `.menu` - but it looks like you want to reposition `ul.menu` within its parent - so you need to show us the HTML and CSS for `<ul.menu`'s ancestor and sibling elements

Comment: You could use `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;` for the element containing your menu.

Comment: @Dai I have added `nav` CSS and other HTML

Comment: try `margin: 0 auto;` on your `.menu` not the best solution, but I think it should work :)

Comment: I have solved my problem with removing from `.logo` `flex : 1;`

Answer (score 0):

```
nav {
   background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   padding: 5px 20px;
   display:flex;
   align-items:center;
   justify-items: center;
}
```

This should fix the issue, justify-items: center; will align the items to the center of the container, check out this link for more explanation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-items

Answer (score 0):

I understand it is necessary to place a menu? Add `margin: auto;` to `.menu`. Your snippet:

```css
nav {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 5px 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto; /*  */
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-bar">
</div>
<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="views.png">
  </div>
  <div class="toggle">
    <a href="#">
      <ion-icon name="menu-outline"></ion-icon>
    </a>
  </div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Подписка</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Кино</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Сериалы</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <ion-icon name="log-out-outline"></ion-icon>Войти</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```